# can't save data to bigquery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-composer

i'm really need a help from you guys i'm really appreciate every little things you can help me!
so, i create a dag to do a sparkjob in cloud composer and here is my code

spark.py

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import json
from google.cloud import bigquery
import os


def transform():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("transform") \
        .config("spark.jars.packages", "gs://us-east1-airflow-2-17010f65-bucket/jars/mongo-spark-connector_2.12-10.1.1.jar") \
        .getOrCreate()

    df = spark.read.format("mongodb") \
        .option("connection.uri", "mongodb+srv://hageglorie18:wisuda2023@cluster0-pri.i8bur.mongodb.net/") \
        .option("database", "coingecko") \
        .option("collection", "raw_data") \
        .load()
     
    # ubah tipe data, hapus kolom yang tidak digunakan, drop null values 
    df = df.withColumn("created_at", df["created_at"].cast(TimestampType()))
    df_0 = df.na.drop("any")
    df_1 = df_0.drop("symbol", "last_updated")  # (processed_data_1)

    # mencari nilai max created_at
    df_2 = df_1.groupBy('id').agg(F.max('created_at').alias('created_at'))

    # simpan dataframe ke memori
    df_2.persist()

    # join dataframe dengan nilai max created_at dengan processed_data_1
    df_3 = df_1.join(df_2, ['id', 'created_at'], how='inner')\
                        .select(df_1.columns)

    # ekstraksi nilai hour dari created-at
    df_4 = df_3.withColumn("hour", F.date_trunc('hour',F.to_timestamp("created_at","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss 'UTC'")))

    df_4.write \
        .format("com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider") \
        .option("table", "pivotal-spark-393312.coingecko.data_ready") \
        .option("temporaryGcsBucket", "bqtemp_089") \
        .mode("append") \
        .save()
```

but i can save the data to bigquery or even cloud storage

i've tried to run the sparkjob from cloud shell and it works fine, the data has been saved to bigquery but when i run it in composer environment, the table in bigquery didn't have the new data even the dag showing success

i also already edit the service account to allow the dataproc and cloud composer have access to edit bigquery tables but it didn't works

Comment: Can you share your DAG? Can you also check if you have silent error in your project?